# MQTT broker for testing

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Trying to create a Python script that subscribes to an MQTT broker and works with the data. However, the MQTT broker is so far not receiving any data, which makes it difficult to test.

I found the following script to subscribe to a topic and print out the payloads, but it doesn't seem like I can connect to the test broker:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker_url = "iot.eclipse.org"
broker_port = 1883

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
   print("Connected With Result Code "+rc)

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   print("Message Recieved: "+message.payload.decode())

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker_url, broker_port)

client.subscribe("TestingTopic", qos=1)

client.publish(topic="TestingTopic", payload="TestingPayload", qos=1, retain=False)

client.loop_forever()
```

So I would need some MQTT broker and topic that I can subscribe to in order to test my script. Any recommendations how I can find one?

Comment: change to `mqtt.eclipse.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Create local broker, so install on your PC - example https://mosquitto.org/download/
2. Use one online free broker like I am using now: https://www.cloudmqtt.com/

Comment: For anyone visiting after today, CloudMQTT is now a completely paid service.