# Is there a mock MQTT-Broker for unit testing?

Tags: python, pytest, paho

I'm currently working on a module written in python.
In this module, a `paho.mqtt.client.Client` is created, connected to a broker and a few messages are published on a given topic.

Is there an easy way to unit-test this and so to say 'mock' the broker, so that I can verify, that the messages sent were correctly transmitted?

I was looking into this topic a bit but couldn't really find a satisfying solution:

1. The answers on [MQTT broker for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899733/mqtt-broker-for-testing) suggest to either use some online tool, which I guess will not satisfy my need to make any assertions, or alternatively install and run some extra software, which has the same problem and possibly is difficult to share in the team or use on the CI-system.
2. https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.testing/tree/master/interoperability Similar as above. Has to be run in an extra process.
3. https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/tests/testsupport/broker.py This is paho's own solution. This looks the most promising and there I can find inspiration of how to use it in https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/tests/test_client.py . The problem is only, that this is not part of any of the packages I can install in my environment and I really don't want to copy that source.

I would really appreciate some suggestions on how to unit test my MQTT-client without needing to set up a real broker. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do would be to implement a fake broker, as suggested there in paho's solution: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/tests/testsupport/broker.py

Did you try this approach? Which testing library are you using?
This is the typical method used if you want to unit test an API for exemple, by implementing a fake one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using pytest. I also found this solution you mentioned as listed in my question. Do you know of any way to use this, without copy pasting their code? I have to admit, that I'm rather not able to quickly come up with that myself.

Comment: You could create a fixture called fake_broker, that simulate a connection and returns the needed response. For that you can mock the broker Client and assign to it some mocked methods.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote that not so clear. My question was, whether there is a way of getting that code to my project without having to copy-paste it. This FakeBroker is, as far as I see it, not part of the distributed package of paho. But if that's what it takes, I will just have to accept that I think.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You could use it as inspiration, but it would be the easiest way to copy-paste and adapt it a bit with what you need.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. Then I will go with this solution.

Comment: @Christian did you have success with this idea? Thinking of doing something similar

Comment: @Tsaari sorry for the delayed response. But yes - I actually managed, with copying the code from the broker.py that Bloodbee posted though. You can check for example the https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/tests/test_client.py for some inspiration how to use it then. It worked for me.